# Compute the variance in a result derived from a unit quaternion, when the quaternion variance-covariance matrix is known.

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance, kalman-filter

I would like to compute the variance in a quantity derived from a unit quaternion. The variance-covariance matrix of the quaternion is known because the quaternion forms part of a Kalman filter's state. Specifically, I am looking for the variance in the inclination and azimuth derived from the quaternion (formulas given below).

**Some background**

The unit quaternion is defined as $\mathbf{q}=(q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)^T$, $|\mathbf{q}|=1$ where the scalar component is $q_0$. The global coordinate system has $\hat{x}$ north, $\hat{y}$ east, and $\hat{z}$ down. The quaternion represents the transformation from the global coordinate system to a rotated body coordinate system.

The variance-covariance matrix for $\mathbf{q}$ is the 4x4 matrix $\mathbf{P}$.

**Derived values**

Two of the values derived from the quaternion are:

- $\theta=\cos^{-1}(q^2_0-q^2_1-q^2_2+q^2_3)$
- $\phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{q_2q_3-q_0q_1}{q_0q_2+q_1q_3}$

Given the trig functions, some of these values will be indeterminate (e.g. for inclination $\theta=0$ or $\pi$, azimuth $\phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{0}{0}$). I imagine that some linearization of the inverse trig functions would be in order, but I am completely in the dark about how to derive Var$[\theta]$ or Var$[\phi]$ given $\mathbf{q}$, $\mathbf{P}$, and the above expressions.

Comment: Variance is normally associated with zero mean Gaussian white noise (especially in the context of Kalman filters). However, the distribution of the unit quaternion will not be normally distributed, because it is constrained to unit length. Similarly, after those nonlinear functions the distribution will change, most likely in another non-Gaussian distribution. From those distribution one could use the standard formula to calculate a variance, but this might not give optimal result as with Kalman filter since those assume Gaussian distributions. So what do you intend to do with these variances?

Comment: The intent is to give the user some estimate of how confident the Kalman filter is with regard to the orientation of the body. The reported variance need not be very accurate or correct, but it has to be reported in reference to quantities that are easy to visualize (e.g. azimuth and inclination) rather than the quaternion (which is somewhat abstract).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this question cannot be answered as posed. Without expected-value information about the elements of the quaternion (much less the higher powers of the quaternion elements that result when the trig functions are expanded), there is not enough information to derive a solution.